# how to trim thi url for iphone

Tags: iphone

how to remove degrre symbol form this URL

NSString *s=  http://www.com/appfeed/default.php?app=1.31223**°**|103.865**°**|56a76d

i want to trim that degree symbol( lat and long ) from this string plz help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

You can use the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString` method.

```
s = [ s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"°" withString: @"" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using bitly.[Click here](http://github.com/dbloete/bitly-iphone) to get example in which url is trim using bitly api.